# Prove |a|<2|a-b| if 2|b|<|a|

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles, absolute-value

I have already proved the triangle inequality

### $\vert a+b \vert \le \vert a \vert + \vert b \vert$

I also proved that

### $\vert a \vert - \vert b \vert \le \vert a-b \vert $

and that

### $\vert \vert a \vert - \vert b \vert \vert \le \vert a-b \vert $

Now I just need help proving that

### if $ 2\vert b \vert \lt \vert a \vert $ then $\vert a \vert \lt 2\vert a-b \vert$

Comment: I think we can not say that it's "on hold" because Elina showed her previous work.  I think we need to open this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2|a-b|\geq2||a|-|b||=2||a|-|b||-|a|+|a|=$$
$$=\frac{4(|a|-|b|)^2-|a|^2}{2||a|-|b||+|a|}+|a|=\frac{(|a|-2|b|)(3|a|-2|b|)}{2||a|-|b||+|a|}+|a|>|a|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the "reverse triangle equality" (the second one in your list) you get
$$
 2|a -b | \ge  2 |a|  - 2 |b| > 2 |a| - |a| = |a|
$$